# SPARQL query hierarchical data using rdf and tpl

Tags: rdf, sparql, hierarchy, apache-jena

I am a bit new to sparql Query and I am having a lot of trouble producing a simple data set. Basically here's what I am trying to do. Given the following data structure:

```
 Data
     -Composition
           -ElementName:"A"
           -Value      :"4"
```

I want to output something like the following

```
----------------------- 
| elementName | Value |
 =====================
| "A"         | "1"   |
| "B"         | "2"   |
| "C"         | "3"   |
| "D"         | "4"   |
-----------------------
```

USing the the following code

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX tpl: <http://www.example.com/1962c0ea39923156f8ef72fa44584f26e7c5ae20#>

SELECT ?elementNameValue ?valueValue
WHERE {
{
?s tpl:Data/tpl:composition/tpl:elementName ?o .
?o rdf:value ?elementNameValue .
}
UNION
 {
?s tpl:Data/tpl:composition/tpl:value ?o .
?o rdf:value ?valueValue .
}
}
```

I am outputting

```
----------------------- 
| elementName | Value |
 =====================
| "A"         |       |
| "B"         |       |
| "C"         |       |
| "D"         |       |
|             | "1"   |
|             | "2"   |
|             | "3"   |
|             | "4"   |
-----------------------
```

What am i doing wrong? directions to resources are also helpful. using APache-Jena

Comment: What happens when you write `SELECT ?elementNameValue ?valueValue
WHERE {
{
?s tpl:Data/tpl:composition/tpl:elementName|tpl:value ?o .
?o rdf:value ?elementNameValue .
?o rdf:value ?valueValue .
}`

Answer (score 1):

The [SPARQL spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) is your number one resource.

Regarding your question, the Union construct as per your query is for matching alternatives e.g. `?elementNameValue` is bound for solutions from the first branch of the UNION, and `?valueValue` for solutions from the second branch.

If you are looking for something in the equivalent of an inner join (e.g. results that match both a name and a value), then removing the union may be what you are after:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX tpl: <http://www.example.com/1962c0ea39923156f8ef72fa44584f26e7c5ae20#>

SELECT ?elementNameValue ?valueValue WHERE {
  ?s tpl:Data/tpl:composition/tpl:elementName ?name .
  ?name rdf:value ?elementNameValue .
  ?s tpl:Data/tpl:composition/tpl:value ?value .
  ?value rdf:value ?valueValue .
}
```

which may be optimised:

```
SELECT ?elementNameValue ?valueValue WHERE {
  ?s tpl:Data/tpl:composition ?o .
  ?o tpl:elementName/rdf:value ?elementNameValue;
     tpl:value/rdf:value ?valueValue . 
}
```

This will give you result rows that have both a name and value. See also Joshua Taylor's answer for an alternative form using a blank node variable.

If instead you want something in the equivalent of a full outer join (e.g. results that have either a value or a name or both) then you may look at the Optional construct and formulate your query accordingly. All in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) and pretty straight forward.

Comment: "assuming the smarty syntax is correct, with which I am not familiar" just curious, which part are you referring to there?

Answer (score 1):

Since the query parts:

```sql
?s tpl:Data/tpl:composition/tpl:elementName ?o .
?o rdf:value ?elementNameValue .
```

and

```sql
?s tpl:Data/tpl:composition/tpl:value ?o .
?o rdf:value ?valueValue .
```

are gettting you the parts that you're looking for, I think that you could use a query like this to get the results that you're looking for:

```sql
select ?elementName ?value {
  ?s tpl:Data/tpl:composition ?composition .
  ?composition tpl:elementName/rdf:value ?elementName ;
               tpl:value/rdf:value ?value .
}
```

Now, you can make that even a little bit shorter by using a blank node:

```sql
select ?elementName ?value {
  ?s tpl:Data/tpl:composition [ tpl:elementName/rdf:value ?elementName .
                                tpl:value/rdf:value ?value ]
}
```

But, even better than that, you don't really need the ?s part at all.  Unless it's important that the composition node is the value of tpl:composition of some value of tpl:Data, you can just start right at the composition node:

```sql
select ?elementName ?value {
  [] tpl:elementName/rdf:value ?elementName ;
     tpl:value/rdf:value ?value .
}
```